# Php open TXT max file size

Tags: php

I have a log-view system, you can look through logs with this.

At one point. The file grows to (37.134 KiB) that I think it reached it some max file size, because I look at another logfile which is 27.041 KiB.

Is there any way to solve this?

My code (works like I said with smaller files).

```
 <?php
$search = $_GET["search"]; 
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
// Read from file 
$lines = file($logfile); 
echo"<html><head><title>Admin panel - Search: $search</title></head><body>";
foreach($lines as $line) { // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for,     and print if it does 
if(stristr($line,$search))   // case insensitive
echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
if(empty($line))
{
?>
No results
<?php
}
}


                                                                                                ?>
</div>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

Do you guys know what the problem is?

Comment: Please take a couple of seconds and unindent your code so we can actually see it.

Comment: There's some imbalanced tags and braces in there, enough I'm not confident in my ability to finish fixing indents. Make sure you got exactly the right chunk?

Comment: Why not format the code properly - make it readable! - Will help in finding bugs as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to load a 37 mo file in memory with "file" is not a very good idea.
Why don't you use fopen and fgets ?

```
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");

while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
{
    if(stristr($line,$search))   // case insensitive
    echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
}

fclose($file);
```